# Need help to deobfuscate malicious PHP malicious file

Tags: php, wordpress, security, obfuscation, malware

I recently found on my WP installation a plugin.php inside plugins that was executed and fortunately returned some errors.

The files begin with:

```
<?php

/**
 * Author: plugin
 * License: GPL v2 or later
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Plugin Name: Plugin
 * Requires PHP: 5.4
 * Requires at least: 5.0
 * Text Domain: plugin
 * Version: 1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit();
}


 #¾êºÐý½s4+{œîÇê7ÀTG4î8TlŸþ§àU,åœàJ›ÒK.-èÒÃåbÀ¢žÇŒ±¤ùâÕDÑ!ò¡,÷YÛIŠ:£‘%½DF¶…àõzejXhøÑ_Ó—'þ6wNÆ†Žh•ÙB¾kn5J¥ðëÒˆ+1eÀ\¶xVÎïFÃã—aÊÅ¨±WAÄ®€>©áBPìXÄW1£@A3æ|ˆé§‚‰À°j„øÈUÊ¶„k'ÕüÒ¿.é¾}¾4óÍz„ßœønœâé.­6Z"vz¦_ÅÕ+—Z7‹ ÷Ó†ÉtÍ£Ë›â©‹wÓ"=£h6íÞéBB    /*%0ÕH‘%0.4‡?.ÅˆuÀÀƒDFÌ!úé•6!ßNnRüôÅ•þÞÊNÂº.$H‘óÏ¿†y•³!Š7àx»Ñ´<ö~Þ|l}ì1²G'RÖº¤mQr»Ÿ3êßUëü•ùÑ@à»Yt²¼42ŽOy4z·–ïÄ‹^«î {ýFVD5¬ˆ_$7çyV8>í¹µÒ7OòžN’…3O¢àÐåF×ß~ÉÅù¿€IØälpŽwÝÌ7\ Š¿@CÜ¡•KßnÚV‚Å9ä­q˜ÞynˆßÿKEIk¯nÆ•RÄŒn1e16;L5›ËÍYð5g˜œ*/
```

and continues. I suspect there is HEX + eval + gzip involved here.

What can I do to know what this file is doing?

Here is a link to the complete file

https://pastebin.com/redDEFJM

I tried some online tools, but got no hints

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that if you download your PasteBin file it matches the exact file you found? Once the comments are stripped out, the code does seem to: assemble an array of strings; concatenate the strings together; attempt to uncompress the result using gzinflate; and then would eval the result if the gzinflate was not failing due to invalid data.

There are a number of special characters in the original strings, so I'm wondering if either the copy-and-paste to PasteBin, the rendering PasteBin gives, or the download I'm doing from there is making a small change that is breaking the compressed stream.

I'm going to keep looking at it too, but here's some ideas for dealing with the obfuscation:

- strip the comments out - I used a lazy regex of `/\*.*?\*/`
- you end up (in the obfuscated bit) with three statements

  - an assignment to an array of 252 items
  - an assignment to a new single-value array of the last item (which is just 'gzinflate')
  - eval of the output of running 'gzinflate' on the concatenation of the remaining array items
- so you could just take the first statement to form the array, then concatenate the entries as done in the last statement
- this would then be able to be passed to gzinflate, and the output should give you the code it is trying to execute